# SQL Table Partitioning and filegroup backup restore

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, restore, database-backups

I have set of 4 tables that are partitioned on same column(int) and written to same secondary filegroup/file.

I am looking for help with restoring specific backup of this filegroup. also if i merged the older partition range to remove the file(basically to archive old and have only no of filegroups at a given time) and restore it at a later point cause of any need..is it possible?

I tried to delete data from one of the tables in a filegroup and tried to restore from earlier filegroup backup but didn't see any deleted data being restore.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sql server 2017